# Why won't text shadow show on this button?

Tags: html, css

I have a button being used in an overlay. I can't see why the text shadow won't display on the "find out more" text within the button.

HTML:

```
 <a href="http://www.mysite.co.uk/promotions/cashback.htm" class="apply">Find out more<img src="img/glyphicons-224-chevron-right.png" class="chevronr" alt="some_text"></a>
```

CSS:

```
.apply {
  display: inline-block;
  background: linear-gradient(#98e901 ,#5ba119);
  vertical-align: middle;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 0 rgba(69,69,69,.11);
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 0, 4, 4, 0;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding-top: 8px;
  padding-right: 42px;
  padding-bottom: 8px;
  padding-left: 42px;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: Raleway, arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 800;
  font-size: 28px;
  line-height: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  letter-spacing: -1px;
}
```

I can't see anything in my styling that would conflict but when testing the browser isn't rendering the text shadow?

Comment: `text-shadow: 0, 4, 4, 0;` is not valid.
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_text-shadow.asp

Comment: Because `0, 4, 4, 0` is not a valid value for `text-shadow` property https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-shadow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `text-shadow` property is invalid. With 4 properties, it should be of the format `offset-x offset-y blur-radius color` or `color offset-x offset-y blur-radius`. Note the use of space separators rather than the comma separators - commas are used to separate multiple shadows.

To rewrite the example provided in your question, making assumptions about the intent, it would be:

```
text-shadow: 0 4px 4px #000;
```

[More information on `text-shadow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-shadow)

Answer (score 1):

Try like this: **[Demo 1](http://jsfiddle.net/rucbn9vx/)**

```
 text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #000;
```

or like this: **[Demo 2](http://jsfiddle.net/rucbn9vx/1/)**

```
text-shadow: 0px 4px rgba(0, 4, 4, 0.4);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have used

```
text-shadow: 0, 4, 4, 0;
```

Which, unfortunately, has a few things wrong with it.

The Text-shadow property takes the values of

```
Value: none | [<color> || <length> <length> <length>? ,]* [<color> || <length> <length> <length>?] | inherit
```

> This property accepts a comma-separated list of shadow effects to be
>   applied to the text of the element. The shadow effects are applied in
>   the order specified and may thus overlay each other, but they will
>   never overlay the text itself. ~ [w3.org](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-CSS2/text.html)

This means that it takes only three values, and not four.

You are also missing units for your declaration (I have used `px` for this demo).

```
text-shadow: 3px 3px 5px red;
```

is a valid declaration.

where it will

*place a shadow to the right and below the element's text. The shadow will have a 5px blur radius and will be red.*

Answer (score 0):

Text-shadow is used usuall with px formatted numbers so

```
text-shadow: 0, 4, 4, 0;
```

must be

```
 text-shadow: 0px  4px 4px ;
```